# MS Access - Input into a table from a form a calculated expression

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013, ms-access-2016

I have a table which has a `Birthday` field. I also have a form where I can enter data into the table.

I want to enter the age of a person to the form, and calculate the Birthday year automatically (`Birthday = CurrentYear - Age`).

How can I input calculated data referencing the form as the `Birthday` field?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the **Name** of the textbox where you enter their age is **txt_Age**, the **Control Source** for the text box that displays their birthyear should have the following formula:

```
=Year(DateAdd("yyyy",([txt_Age]*-1),Date()))
```

Comment: Yeah, but how can I bind that also to the table?

Comment: Write a query that is triggered when you update the field.  The query would look something like this:  `UPDATE Age_Table SET Age_Table.Birthyear = Year(DateAdd("yyyy",([Forms]![Form1]![txt_Age]*-1),Date()))
WHERE (((Age_Table.age_id)=[Forms]![Form1]![age_id]));`